# NoMethodError: Intersection function method not found for arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am writing a script where I would like to use the [`.intersection`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#method-i-intersection) method on Array. But when I call the method on an array I get `NoMethodError`. See full IRB output:

```sh
larsnielsen@darkstar ruby % irb
irb(main):001:0> x = ["a", "b"]
=> ["a", "b"]
irb(main):002:0> y = ["a", "c"]
=> ["a", "c"]
irb(main):003:0> x.intersection y
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/larsnielsen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/larsnielsen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/larsnielsen/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):3
NoMethodError (undefined method `intersection' for ["a", "b"]:Array)
```

I am running Ruby 2.6.5p114 and from what I can tell the function should exist in this version.

Minimal working example:

```rb
x = ["a", "b"]
y = ["a", "c"]
x.intersection y
```

Comment: That's because you're using Ruby 2.6.5, and Array#intersection was added just in Ruby 2.7. You can either upgrade Ruby or implement your own.

Comment: ... thanks. I was looking at an example claiming to use ruby 2.6.5 so I assumed it was there. Should have check docs.

Comment: No prob. As per the docs, it's just an underlying implementation of Set#intersection and Array#eql?, so it shouldn't be that complicated if you're unable to upgrade Ruby. Cheers ;)

Comment: I will update :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check version Ruby in your computer
intersection method only support for Ruby 2.6

If you using ruby 2.5, you could `&`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a", "b"]
y = ["a", "c"]
x & y #["a"]
```

You can follow above code to accomplish your Array intersection.